# How can I transform a list of indices into a 1d boolean tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like a tf.function to return a 1d boolean tensor of fix length with each matching index range to True from a label file. The index ranges can overlap. But I am stuck at converting the indices to a flat boolean tensor.

I am reading a file where each row is a label and a start and end index from a fix length. For this example we can say that the fix length is 50.

Label file content example:

```
frog 4.0 10.0
frog 20.0 30.0
goat 2.0 20.0
camel 4.0 15.0
```

Here it would be

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is a tf.function that works well so far but I am stuck on how to get the final tensor. I am executing this tf.function using a dataset.map(load_label).

```
def load_label(file_path, accepted_labels=['goat', 'frog']):
    label_datas = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    label_datas = tf.strings.strip(label_datas)
    label_datas = tf.strings.split(label_datas, sep='\n')
    label_datas = tf.strings.split(label_datas, sep=' ')

    label_datas = label_datas.to_tensor(default_value='0.0', shape=[None, 3])

    list_of_indices = []
    for label_data in label_datas:
        equal = tf.math.equal(label_data[0], accepted_labels)
        if tf.reduce_any(equal):
            start = tf.strings.to_number(label_data[1], out_type=tf.float32)
            end = tf.strings.to_number(label_data[2], out_type=tf.float32)
            start = tf.cast(start, tf.int32)
            end = tf.cast(end, tf.int32)

            list_of_indices.append(tf.range(start, end, 1))

    list_of_indices = tf.concat(list_of_indices, axis=0)

    list_of_indices, idx = tf.unique(list_of_indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution using tensorArray and reduce_sum.

I am sure it can be further optimised. Here it is:

```
def load_label(file_path, accepted_labels=['goat', 'frog']):
    label_datas = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    label_datas = tf.strings.strip(label_datas)
    label_datas = tf.strings.split(label_datas, sep='\n')
    label_datas = tf.strings.split(label_datas, sep=' ')

    label_datas = label_datas.to_tensor(default_value='0.0', shape=[None, 3])

    label_ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False)
    ta_index_count = 0
    for label_data in label_datas:
        equal = tf.math.equal(label_data[0], accepted_labels)
        if tf.reduce_any(equal):
            start = tf.strings.to_number(label_data[1], out_type=tf.float32)
            end = tf.strings.to_number(label_data[2], out_type=tf.float32)
            start = tf.cast(start, tf.int32)
            end = tf.cast(end, tf.int32)

            label_ta = label_ta.write(ta_index_count, tf.concat(
                [tf.zeros((start), dtype=tf.int32),
                 tf.ones((end - start), dtype=tf.int32),
                 tf.zeros((new_length - end), dtype=tf.int32)], 0))
        else:
            label_ta = label_ta.write(ta_index_count, tf.zeros((new_length), dtype=tf.int32))
        ta_index_count = ta_index_count + 1

    label_ta = label_ta.stack()
    label_ta = tf.reduce_sum(label__ta, 0)
    label_ta = tf.where(label_ta > 0, 1, 0)
    return label_ta
```